# How to fix error ,Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id').
**but when i change my initialState (object ) then it works fine**

```
type AnchorElAction = {
  id: string;
  domTarget: React.ReactNode;
} | null;

const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState<AnchorElAction | null>(null);


return (
       {events?.map((event, index) => {
          return (
            <Styled.Event key={`${event.id}:${event.name}`} onClick={handleOpenPopover(event.id)}>
              {renderShifts(event)}
              {anchorEl.id === event.id && (
                <ShiftPopover
                  start={event.start}
                  end={event.end}
                  name={event.name}
                  id={event.id}
                  onClose={handleCloseModal}
                  anchorEl={anchorEl.domTarget}
                  open={Boolean(anchorEl.domTarget)}
                />
              )}
            </Styled.Event>
          );
        })}
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cuz when you do

```
const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState<AnchorElAction | null>(null);
```

anchorEl === null so you can't do anchorEl.id

when you do

```
const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState<AnchorElAction>({});
```

you can access property id in anchorEl
so anchorEl === {}
and anchorEl.id === null

To fix that, remove null or check when use anchorEl.id like

```
anchorEl?.id
// if anchorEl === null => anchorEl?.id === null
//if anchorEl === {}  => anchorEl?.id === nulll
//if anchorEl === {id : 'any id'} => anchorEl?.id === 'any id'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could you the `.?` operator.

In your case, `event.id` you should be changed to `event?.id`. In order to avoid similar issues, I would add the `.?` operator every time you access a property of `event` or any other variable that could be `null` or `undefined`.

For more information about it, please refer to the [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html).